# How to create a side menu in titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-studio

I'm starting to program the Titanium Studio and I'm having trouble creating a laterial menu. I wonder how I create this menu and also how I can call every menu option in my app.js

Comment: try http://www.tidev.io/2013/12/10/slide-menus-ios-android/ 
and 
https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/154460/facebook-like-slider-menu---both-android-and-ios

Answer (score 1):

the most known way is to use the side drawer navigation component from https://github.com/viezel/NappDrawer

Answer (score 0):

As csg already mentioned about the NappDrawer module for side drawer navigation.
If you are working with Alloy framework(which you should be working now), You can use these widgets

1. http://github.com/mdpauley/com.mdpauley.frostedsidebar
2. https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.drawer
3. https://github.com/MadRocket/com.madrocket.ti.slidemenu